# Why java applications have UI text cut in half?

Tags: java

i don't care much about the fonts themselves, but the line height is cut in half for most awt applications.

eclipse and intellij looks great. but here's jmeter (i'm using some options that makes the font look better, but it doesn't matter at all for the line height problem)

```
$ jmeter
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame (file:/usr/share/jmeter/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar) to field sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.awtAppClassName
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

[image]

edit 1:
after taking the screen shot i noticed i had the menu for look and feel open, which I didn't know about. Changing to GTK+ fix the line height in the menu, not in the buttons. But it then also breaks the colors. You can see on the left it's white text on white background

[image]

Comment: AWT has been around since the mid 90. It was developed for VGA screens. I'd go for a QT or (maybe) GTK solution. But: it will run on your raspi connected to a non HD screen.

Comment: this is not a high dpi display. using 100% scalling with 1200 vertical pixels. almost a SVGA :(